# Sync model with localstorage sencha touch

Tags: model, sencha-touch-2, local-storage, synchronization

I need to get data from my server and sync model with my localstorage

Here is my code

model.js

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.model.BlueButton.Loyalty', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'loyaltyModel',
        fields: [
             { name: 'fullName' },
             { name: 'age' },

             {  name: 'lastvisited'  },
             {  name: 'consumer_bbID'  },
             {  name: 'merchant_bbID'  },
             {  name: 'sessionId'  },
             {  name: 'deviceId'  },

             {  name: 'updatedPoint'  },
             { name: 'currentPoint' },

             {  name: 'action'  },
             {  name: 'result'  },
             {  name: 'loyaltyMembership_Id'}



        ],

        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
          url: 'http://192.168.251.131:8080/WebCommon/rest/BBWebService/updateLoyaltyCardPoint',
            reader: 'json',
            actionMethods: {
                create: 'POST',
                read: 'POST',
                update: 'PUT',
                destroy: 'DELETE'
            },


                      noCache: false, // get rid of the '_dc' url parameter

//                    extraParams: {
//                    userid: "test",
//                    // add as many as you need
//                },


//            timeout:300,
//            listeners: {
//                exception: function(proxy, response, operation) {
//                     alert("Connection Problem");
//                       
//                  }
//               },

            reader: {
                type: 'json',

            },

            writer: {
                type: 'json',

            },
        }






    }

});
```

Store.js

```
    Ext.define('bluebutton.store.BlueButton.LoginLS', {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: ['bluebutton.model.BlueButton.Login'],
    config: {


         model :'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.Login',

         proxy: {
             type: 'localstorage',
             id: 'loginLS'
         }


    }
});
```

View.js

```
 Ext.define('bluebutton.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'loginview',
    id: 'loginview',
    requires: [
        'bluebutton.view.Main',
        'Ext.field.Password',
        'bluebutton.store.BlueButton.LoginLS'
    ],

    config: {
        labelWidth: 80,
        frame: true,
        title: 'Please Login',

        items: [

                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            id: 'bbID',
                            label: 'User ID',

                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'passwordfield',
                            id: 'bbPassword',
                            label: 'Password',

                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Login',
                            id:'btnLogin',
//                            handler: function () {


//                            }
                        },
```

How can i sync my model with localstorage when i press login button?Please guide me so solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your store is `bluebutton.store.BlueButton.LoginLS`?

Try to call:

`Ext.getStore('LoginLS').sync();`

Procedure that works for me:
Name of my Store is e.g.: `MyApp.store.settings.Settings`.
 
To get this Store I simply call `var settings = Ext.getStore('Settings');`
Now I can add, remove items from store and then sync: `settings.sync();`

Check out whether your store is defined in app.js or not.

Answer (score 2):

Set the dirty flag on your model object when you create it:

```
  var loyalty = Ext.create('bluebutton.model.BlueButton.Loyalty', { ... });
  loyalty.setDirty(true);  // <== missing step!
  var store = Ext.getStore('blueButtonStore');
  store.add(loyalty);
  store.sync();
```

You can also set the autoSync: true and autoLoad: true for the store config to avoid having to do store.load() and store.sync() .

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the issue, but you could add a `storeId` property to the store, such as 'blueButtonStore', and sync like so:

```
Ext.getStore('blueButtonStore').sync();
```

To load the store with what exists in local storage, you would use

```
Ext.getStore('blueButtonStore').load();
```

Let me know if that isn't speaking to your problem.

Comment: i try Ext.getStore('blueButtonStore').sync(); but get empty value